# It is possible to show panoramic view of a jpeg/png on android?

Tags: android, panoramas

It is possible to show panoramic view of a jpeg/png on android ?

Thank's for your help

Comment: yes, it is, use ImageView with matrix scale type

Comment: you mean handle ontouch screen, drag, zoom ... can we call this panorama 360  ° ?

Comment: well, there is no PaniramicView widget out of the box...

Comment: My boss tell me to use https://developers.theta360.com/en/docs/sdk/   but it require only spherical image

Comment: never heard of that library so cannot say much